# Hadoop MapReduce confusion for AWS EMR service

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, emr

I just feel confused of the MapReduce mechanism AWS EMR performs. From what I understand, you just need to identify the directory of your input files, identify the mapper and reducer function and EMR would help you with shuffle and sorting. However, when I tried to run a word-count-like program, it just fails.

I was trying to removed repeated Ids(first field) from csv files like this:

```
1712783,AA,B,C
28218,m,wiw,oo
28218,oqoo,now,ee
76812,wpq,oei,od
23192,kwl,lqo,pr,
23192,qow,pd,82,
1712783,qow,lf,s
...
```

There were put under a same directory. My mapper program simply prints out these lines and hope EMR could help me sort entries with same ids.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

And my reducer program was trying to read each entry and tried to identify whether this entry has the same id as last one. Ignore ones that has same id as before.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;
    String lastId = null;
    String currentId = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        currentId = line.split(",")[0];
        if(lastId == null || !currentId.equals(lastId){
            lastId = currentId
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
}
```

When I tried to run the program on my local machine with one specific file and bash script to simulate bash sort process, it works well. However, when I tried my program on EMR, I found the result files `part-00000, part-00001, part00002 ...` are partial sorted, entries were sorted by ids inside each files and there were some cases where same id appeared in different files. How could that happened? It looks like EMR did map reduce work individually inside each files, instead of the whole directory. Has someone met this circumstance before? I thought the result files should be sorted totally and I could build an entire sorted file by connecting each portions along.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: @BinaryNerd By using screaming process on AWS EMR